# Why is element access for typed lists so much slower than for arrays with Numba?

Tags: python, arrays, list, performance, numba

I wonder why accessing elements is so much slower for typed Lists than for NumPy arrays when using Numba. I have this minimal example shown below. I generate indices randomly to prevent any compiler optimization behind the scenes. It seems that after correcting for the time it takes to generate all these random numbers, each element access occurs almost instant (<1ns) in the case of NumPy arrays, whereas for the typed list, each access takes up to 100 ns. Maybe one should expect that typed Lists are a bit slower, but this seems too much of a difference to me and could significantly slow down code if one needs to access list elements a lot. Unfortunately, I am not a computer science expert, so I probably lack some basic background knowledge on how the access operation works on these two different data structures. So, do you have any idea why there is such a significant difference in access speed?

```py
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

@nb.njit
def only_rand(N):
    
    for _ in range(10000):
        
        i = np.random.randint(N)
        j = np.random.randint(N)

@nb.njit
def foo(pos, N):
    
    for _ in range(10000):
        
        i = np.random.randint(N)
        j = np.random.randint(N)
        
        dx = pos[i][0] - pos[j][0]
        dy = pos[i][1] - pos[j][1]
        dz = pos[i][2] - pos[j][2]
        

N = 100

Array = np.random.rand(N,3)
List = nb.typed.List(Array)

print('Random number generation:')
%timeit only_rand(N)
print('Numpy Array:')
%timeit foo(Array, N)
print('Typed List:')
%timeit foo(List, N)
```

Out:

```
Random number generation:
133 µs ± 4.92 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
Numpy Array:
132 µs ± 881 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
Typed List:
947 µs ± 74 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem is that the **benchmark is flawed**. Indeed, the Numba JIT compiler can (partially) see that your computation is mostly useless since it *mostly* does not have a *computational visible impact*: `dx`, `dy` and `dz` are not read and thus their computation (eg. `pos[i][0] - pos[j][0]`) can be simply ignored. The same seems to apply for `i` and `j` at first glance but this is not the case: `np.random.randint` modify an internal seed causing a *side effects*. This side effect force the compiler to still compute partially the loop.

However, besides the above point, the list-based implementation is indeed slower once the benchmark fixed. It comes from the **reference counting** of the temporary lists. and the fact that the assembly code is **less well optimized by the JIT** (lists tends to generate a more complex code harder to optimize).

---

### In-depth analysis:

To see that the JIT optimize the code, you can just increase a lot the value of `N`. Here are timings on my machine:

```
With N=100:
  Random number generation:
  109 µs ± 13.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 2000 loops each)
  Numpy Array:
  113 µs ± 22.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 2000 loops each)
  Typed List:
  806 µs ± 197 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 250 loops each)

With N=1_000_000:
  Random number generation:
  64.7 µs ± 13.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 2000 loops each)
  Numpy Array:
  68.6 µs ± 23.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 2000 loops each)
  Typed List:
  804 µs ± 215 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 250 loops each)

With N=10_000_000:
  Random number generation:
  185 µs ± 13.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 2000 loops each)
  Numpy Array:
  190 µs ± 23.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 2000 loops each)
  Typed List:
  839 µs ± 200 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 250 loops each)
```

Note that the time are not very dependant of `N`.

The assembly code of the two implementation is pretty huge but one can see that the main loop are similar and contains in both case calls to `numba_rnd_shuffle` which are not optimized (due to the side effect of `np.random.randint`). Here is an example:

```py
.LBB0_20: <----------\
        cmpl    $624, %eax
        jae     .LBB0_21
.LBB0_22: <----------\
        movl    %eax, %ecx
        movl    4(%rsi,%rcx,4), %ebp
        leal    1(%rax), %ecx
        movl    %ecx, (%rsi)
        movl    %ebp, %edx
        shrl    $11, %edx
        xorl    %ebp, %edx
        movl    %edx, %ebp
        shll    $7, %ebp
        andl    $-1658038656, %ebp
        xorl    %edx, %ebp
        movl    %ebp, %edx
        shll    $15, %edx
        andl    $-272236544, %edx
        xorl    %ebp, %edx
        movl    %edx, %ebp
        shrl    $18, %ebp
        xorl    %edx, %ebp
        andl    %edi, %ebp
        cmpl    $623, %eax
        jae     .LBB0_23
.LBB0_24: <----------\
        movl    %ecx, %eax
        movl    4(%rsi,%rax,4), %eax
        incl    %ecx
        movl    %ecx, (%rsi)
        movl    %eax, %edx
        shrl    $11, %edx
        xorl    %eax, %edx
        movl    %edx, %eax
        shll    $7, %eax
        andl    $-1658038656, %eax
        xorl    %edx, %eax
        movl    %eax, %edx
        shll    $15, %edx
        andl    $-272236544, %edx
        xorl    %eax, %edx
        movl    %edx, %eax
        shrl    $18, %eax
        xorl    %edx, %eax
        shlq    $32, %rbp
        orq     %rax, %rbp
        movl    %ecx, %eax
        cmpq    %r14, %rbp
        jge     .LBB0_20 ---------->
        jmp     .LBB0_12
.LBB0_21:
        movq    %rsi, %rcx
        movabsq $numba_rnd_shuffle, %rax
        callq   *%rax
        movl    $0, (%rsi)
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        jmp     .LBB0_22 ---------->
.LBB0_23:
        movq    %rsi, %rcx
        movabsq $numba_rnd_shuffle, %rax
        callq   *%rax
        movl    $0, (%rsi)
        xorl    %ecx, %ecx
        jmp     .LBB0_24 ---------->
        .p2align        4, 0x90
```

The thing is that at the end of each iteration, the following assembly code is repeated 6 times:

```py
        movabsq $numba_list_size_address, %rdi

        movq    %r13, %rcx
        movabsq $NRT_incref, %rax
        callq   *%rax                  # NRT_incref(ptrVar);

        movq    %r15, %rcx
        callq   *%rdi                  # tmp1 = numba_list_size_address(listVar);

        movq    %rbp, %r12
        sarq    $63, %r12
        movq    (%rax), %rbx           # tmp2 = fancy_operation(*tmp1)
        andq    %r12, %rbx
        addq    %rbp, %rbx
        js      .LBB0_34               # Conditional goto to the end (overflow check?)

        movq    %r15, %rcx
        callq   *%rdi                  # tmp3 = numba_list_size_address(listVar);

        movq    %r15, %rdi
        movq    (%rax), %r15
        movq    %r13, %rcx
        movabsq $NRT_decref, %rax
        callq   *%rax                  # NRT_decref(ptrVar);

        cmpq    %r15, %rbx             # if(*tmp3 >= tmp2)
        jge     .LBB0_33               #     goto end;

        movq    %rdi, %rcx
        movabsq $numba_list_base_ptr, %rax
        callq   *%rax                  # numba_list_base_ptr(listVar);
```

One can see the reference counting calls as well as list-related functions. This portion of the assembly code comes from the expressions `pos[i]` and `pos[j]`. The reference counting of the list objects are not optimized by the JIT. This also appear to be the case for related checks.

I guess this is because Numba function calls cannot be optimized in this case or is assumed not to be enough expensive by the JIT. The code of the list-related functions can be found [here](https://github.com/numba/numba/blob/master/numba/typed/listobject.py). I find it weird that the JIT do not optimize the list-related function calls since they are mark as `alwaysinline` and `readonly` by Numba... Anyway, I think it is a *missed optimization* and it can be improved.

I submitted an issue to Numba developers [here](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/7533).